# Combing multiple rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following  table

```
Index    BookNumber  
  2         51 
  2         52 
  2         53 
  1         41  
  1         42 
  1         43
```

I am trying to come up with the following output

```
Index    BookNumber1  Booknumber2  Booknumber3  
----------------------------------------------
  1         41             42           43   
  2         51             52           53
```

I was able to come up with the following query , however the output is unexpected

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    index,
    CASE WHEN index = 1 THEN Booknumber END AS BookNumber1,
    CASE WHEN index = 2 THEN Booknumber END AS BookNumber2,
    CASE WHEN index = 3 THEN Booknumber END AS BookNumber3
FROM Mytable;
```

I get following output

```
Index    BN1    BN2    BN3  
------------------------------
  1      41     null   null 
  1      null   42     null 
  1      null   null   43 
  2      51     null   null 
  2      null   52     null 
  2      null   null   53
```

Is there a way to compress this to only 2 rows?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need any of those crappy `&nbsp;` and `<br>` tags, either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure how the `index` in your query matches the `index` column in your data.  But the query that you want is:

```
SELECT index,
       max(CASE WHEN index = 1 THEN Booknumber END) AS BookNumber1 ,
       max(CASE WHEN index = 2 THEN Booknumber END) AS BookNumber2,
       max(CASE WHEN index = 3 THEN Booknumber END) AS BookNumber3
FROM Mytable
GROUP BY index;
```

Give your data, the query seems more like:

```
SELECT index,
       max(CASE WHEN ind = 1 THEN Booknumber END) AS BookNumber1 ,
       max(CASE WHEN ind = 2 THEN Booknumber END) AS BookNumber2,
       max(CASE WHEN ind = 3 THEN Booknumber END) AS BookNumber3
FROM (select mt.*, row_number() over (partition by index order by BookNumber) as ind
      from Mytable mt
     ) mt
GROUP BY index;
```

By the way, "index" is a reserved word, so I assume that it is just a placeholder for another column name.  Otherwise, you need to escape it with double quotes or square braces.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always 3 or fewer book numbers for each index, you could use:

```
with data as
 (select idx,
         booknumber as bn1,
         lag(booknumber, 1) over(partition by idx order by idx, booknumber) as bn2,
         lag(booknumber, 2) over(partition by idx order by idx, booknumber) as bn3
    from books)
select *
  from data
 where data.bn1 = (select max(x.bn1) from data x where x.idx = data.idx)
```

sqlfiddle demo is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8dc82/5/0

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that index is a reserved word. Personally I prefer not to use reserved words as column names, but you can compensate by using square brackets like in my example.

This will work from sqlserver 2008+

```
declare @t table([Index] int, BookNumber int)
insert @t values
(2,51),(2,52),(2,53),(1,41),(1,42),(1,43)

;with cte as
(
select [Index], BookNumber, 
row_number() over (partition by [Index] order by BookNumber) rn
from @t
)
select [Index], [1] as Booknumber1, [2] as Booknumber2, [3] as Booknumber3
from cte
pivot (max([booknumber]) FOR [rn] IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS pvt
```

Result:

```
Index Booknumber1 Booknumber2 Booknumber3
1     41          42          43
2     51          52          53
```